# is expo crypto secure for storing credit card information?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have to store credit card information in my database. this should be encrypted.

It is ok to encrypt this with expo crypto lib ?

Comment: Unless you have PCI compliance in place, it's not ok to even store it encrypted.

Comment: What is PCI ..?

Comment: It's the major standard that specifies how credit card data must be handled, for which you **must** comply to legally store such information. [Have a look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard) for a brief introduction. Since you didn't even know of it, I can only strongly recommend that you **DO NOT STORE ANY CREDIT CARD DATA IN ANY WAY**, encrypted or not.

Comment: How ebay does it ? Or Amazon? If you can sell products in my app, and the money came to your bank depot, then I have to know this credit data. So if I not store it where I get it then ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a company the size of Ebay or Amazon have PCI compliance in place. But in any case, for the vast majority of companies, payments are done though payment processors, where they handle the confidential data client-side without ever reaching your servers. Even if your program absolutely must come in contact with credit card data, you just pass along to the payment procesor and throw it away immediately. Without PCI, you're not legally allowed to store it, and you'll be held liable for any problem in case you do. Look at the documentation of your payment processor for the details.

Comment: @Alejandro I am very thankful for your good explained answer. But I dont know what I have to do now. Every user can create Products. So if anyone buy an item, then the money have to go to his bank account. So how I solve this problem now ? Do you have an idea ?

Comment: So basically it's an ecommerce site? Forget about code for a moment, what you really need right now is a way to take payments. Look for a *payment processor* for your country (a company whose job is to take and charge credit cards for purchases. Once you've chosen one, look for its developer documentation for ways on how do you interface with them. Then we can go back to the code, now knowing what were after exactly.

Comment: @Alejandro I have seen stripe. there offers pci dss and secure transaction. Do you know stripe ? Is that correctly ? I am very thankful for your answer , as you not answered I were in trouble :D

Comment: No idea at all of what stripe is to begin with :D. But a quick Google search seems to confirm you're on the right track. You can look for its developer documentation for instructions on how to use then, including the secure treatment of confidential data. Very likely, you'll just have to pass over credit card information taken from the user, without ever storing it, or even sending to your server. You may look at additional guiadance on the site by looking at the [stripe-payments tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stripe-payments).

Comment: Agree with everything Alejandro said. Don't store card numbers. Stripe is a common solution. I have worked with it before and they offer some nice developer APIs and simple ways to include the Stripe form (Stripe allows you to not even touch the credit card info, providing an embeddable form such that user info goes directly to Stripe).

Comment: @Alejandro hi, i have a small question can apps developed using react native expo CLI be PCI compliant or am i required to eject?

Comment: @kd12345 Programs aren't PCI certified, companies are. PCI checks the whole infrastructure of the company, including their servers, some code, storage facilities and security measures. The programs themselves aren't that important, as long as they follow the required workflow. So I guess the answer would be yes, it doesn't really matters what the program is made with.